# Can I check 'mailq' with vzctl from node?

Tags: vps, spam, solusvm

Can I check 'mailq' with vzctl from node? I need to find out if VPS owner from one node sends SPAM messages. Any other way to check if VPS client sends SPAM ?

Answer (score 1):

of course, you can run progam inside the container fromthe host:

vzctl exec CTID mailq

also you can enter the vps:

vzctl enter CTID

Comment: and while you're inside, have a look through the maillog.

Comment: hi, perhaps a best answer choice?